# crystal report datasource to business layer object colletion

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

In my project I want to use data source  for a crystal report as collection of business layer object.
How do I do this? I have 3 projects together in my solution one of them is business object layer.
In grid and comboboxes or other controls I am able to bind these objects to the collection directly.
I know how to bind crystal report to the object collection when class is in the same project but not to the class which is in different project of current solution.

Thank you

Comment: Same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

May be its too late for you, but I'll post an answer, in the case that it helps others.

I had the same problem - where you cannot see the classes from other projects in .NET objects section of Crystal Report, but still you can add them.

Steps to add class as data source from other project:

1. Go to Database Expert
2. Click on Create new connection
3. Make new Connection form ADO.NET (XML)
4. In popup window add a full class name in the editable drop down
5. Click finish

Thats it ...